# How to edit Azure ML entry or scoring script file once it is deployed in aks or aci

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

**I have deployed model endpoint in aci way back 1 month , now i want to change few thing in entry script for same model , so how i can do that without changing the restendpoint .?

My Entry script looks like below :**

```
SENTIMENT_THRESHOLDS = (0.4, 0.7)
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 300
def run(data):
try:
    # Pick out the text property of the JSON request.
    # This expects a request in the form of {"text": "some text to score for sentiment"}
    data = json.loads(data)
    prediction = predict(data['text'])
    #Return prediction
    return prediction
except Exception as e:
    error = str(e)
    return error
```

**Now i want to change the variable SEQUENCE_LENGTH and update the restendpoint with this entry script file **

Answer (score 0):

To re-deploy to ACI is use the :latest tag on your Docker image in the registry. If you re-deploy the image to the registry and re-start ACI to the pointer registry it will auto-deploy the new version/image.

And if you are simply trying to debug and redeploy, doing so locally Please follow the below doc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment#debug-locally

[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-update-web-service) to update the deployed web service using the SDK.